# Watson Assistant With GraphQl

Tags: ibm-watson

Is it possible to use Watson Assistant with  graphql database? I want to make a chatbot for booking/cancelling appointments and I would like to use graphql as the database. If it is possible are there any tutorials on how to connect it all? And if not, what's the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out oasgraph - a GraphQL Wrapper for REST APIs:

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/announcing-oasgraph/

I have seen demos of this for Watson Language Translator and it seemed to do just what you want.